# How to set text in a particular Edittext when gridview is having multiple edittexts?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I m new to grid view in android and i m doing  an application where i made each grid item holding an edit text and if i wanted to set text in a particular cell  then how can i identify this, in my get view() method of my custom adapter class.

Please help on me this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: way of your questioning is bad?